# Can alternate URLs for hreflinks be in different XML sitemap files when using <xml:link rel="alternate"

Tags: seo, googlebot, sitemap, hreflang, rel-alternate

Regarding the XML sitemaps (that use alternative languages), in [this page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en) it is specified the following:

> #### Common Mistakes
>
> Here are the most common mistakes with `hreflang` usage:
>
> Missing return links: **If page X links to page Y, page Y must link back to page X**. If this is not the case for all pages that use hreflang annotations, those annotations may be ignored or not interpreted correctly.

So, if I want to have an URL in 10 languages, I need 10 blocks like this:

```
  <url>
    <loc>...</loc>
    <xhtml:link 
               rel="alternate"
               hreflang="..."
               href="..."/>
    ...
  </url>
```

each one having 1 `<loc>` + 10 `<xhtml:link>` (self + 9 alternatives).

So, only for 1 URL, I'll have 100 `<xhtml:link>` elements.

This way, the 50 MB size limit per file could be easily reached for multiple URLs.

#### Questions

1. Can I have the **"link back" in a different file**? *(for the scenario above: to split the file in 10 files based on language => each URL will have only one `<loc>` element per file)* Or should I keep all URLs together?
2. Is the 50.000 URLs limit counted only for the `<loc>` tags or also for `<xhtml:link>`?